# Newbie php class inheritance question

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, class

I had a problem recently with a php project that I finally realised was down to the way I had structured my classes. If I tried to include more than one class in a page and both classes shared the same parent class, the script failed. I've now resolved the issue but was wondering if someone could explain to me exactly why what I was doing wasn't working, cos I haven't quite got my head around it!
Here's an illustration of what did NOT work:

class A.
class B extends A.
class C extends A.
class D extends B.
class E extends C.

I require class D and class E and the script fails. If class C does not inherit A then it all works fine.
Obviously, it's something to do with requiring class A twice, but could someone explain it in very simple terms for me?!?!?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may declare every class only once. If you require the file where your class is defined more than once, the parser encounters the `class A`, makes an internal lookup and bails: 'Hey, you've already defined that class'. The most simple solution is to put every class into its own file and call `require_once` instead of `require`.

Comment: I think this might be it... I always used require and not require_once as I didn't really know there was any difference! Each class is in it's own file.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have each class in its own file?

Are you using require/include instead of require_once/include_once ?
include_once and require_once do not share the same table of included files either, so you have to use one consistently.

Or consistently use the __autoload function in PHP5.

Answer (score 2):

Any functions or classes defined in [included](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) files are declared in the global scope. This is why you are probably getting redeclaration errors. The solution is to use `require_once` or `include_once` instead of `require` or `include`.

The most elegant way though, is to use a [`__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), but that requires PHP version 5 or later. The only downside to autoloading is that any failure is a fatal error which you can't handle yourself.